# Network Administration Issues

Tags: windows-7

I am on a private server network, on a remote workstation running win7, when trying to setup as a new user with full admin authority, the local computer does not recognize my user and pass as a valid combination. Interesting enough, it does not recognize even our server/system administrators user pass combination as well. What should I or we be looking for to help solve this dilema?

Comment: Is this machine connected to the server in any way? Is it part of the same domain / workgroup? Can it ping the server etc

Comment: Probably not on the domain based on this: "on a remote workstation running win7"

Comment: Do you have AD setup? Are you logging into the domain instead of the local computer? As such: **`[domain name]\[user name]`**?